# Json string to Json using Java and Jolt

Tags: java, json, string, jolt

I have a json string e.g..

```
 { "value": "{\"userSuspended\":false}" }
```

What would be the correct Jolt spec to map 'userSuspended' to 'state'?

Comment: Well, actually you don't have a JSON string. This is not valid JSON syntax.

Comment: You should edit the question, instead of providing corrections in comments.

Comment: Apologies - updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needed two transforms and a Javaclass to map the key/value:

1. Shift "Value":"Value"
2. Map the keys 'userSuspended' and 'false' through a javaclass to key/value pairs
3. Shift the output to "userSuspended":"State"

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to split the value and save what you wanted to state.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "stateArray": "=split('\"',@(1,value))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "stateArray": {
        "1": "state"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, apologies I wasn't very clear - not exactly what I was intending since I wanted the value "false" to be mapped to state.